# PeopleEditor loses focus on overbackspacing

Tags: people-picker

Well, if the user writes anything on PeopleEditor(allowtypein=true) and then from any point of it starts to backspace till the beginning, the PeopleEditor loses focus.

This is a quite annoying problem for people like me who press backspace like crazy until everything is erased. Because the next backspace after the beginning point will just send you the previous page, thanks to back shortcut on backspace.

It is likely due to a SP bug rather than something wrong I have done. Still, I wanted to ask..

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you add some more information on how to repro this? It is working for me in IE 8 with a single select people picker.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this behavior. Tried on both 2007 and 2010 with IE 8, Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Strike out Chrome from my previous comment and look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just received similar complaint from one of my clients. What are the odds?

In Google Chrome after 'too much backspace' in people picker you will end on the previous page. This is not directly SharePoint issue and can be easily solved by installing following Chrome extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gafonhphlnckhffodlclkcadifplniag

This is maybe not the best but it's the simplest solution.

Comment: I should get the habit testing things on multiple browsers :).

Comment: I'd say, the extension solution is far from the best, as disabling backspace is somewhat overkill and making users download an extension is not very handsome. But then, I guess not many users are going to use Chrome for Sharepoint, as a part of our solution depends on ActiveX. Thanks for clearing the issue out.